# Scrapy-splash No module named scrapy_splash. Broken pip

Tags: python, scrapy

I installed scrapy_splash using `pip install`

`python3 -m pip freeze` shows `scrapy-splash==0.7.2`

However, when I ran spider i get following error

```
ImportError: No module named scrapy_splash
```

I suspect that i have problem with some environmental paths.

`which python`
`/usr/bin/python`

`echo $PATH`

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/bin/python3
```

but somehow pip fails

`pip --version`

`bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: /usr/local/bin/python3.7: bad interpreter`

if not specified as `python3.5 -m pip`

I have only python2.7 and python3.5 installed, i removed python3.7 installed from source but it seems that some link is left somewhere which breaks pip, which puts splash in wrong directory. How can i fix it in least painful way?

`pip` and `pip3` is located in `/usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's why people use [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/venv.html). You should not mix your system Python installation with your project-dependant stuff.

Starting with Python 3.3, you can create new virtual environment `venv` in current directory like this:

```
python3 -m venv venv
```

Then do

```
cd venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install -U pip <project-dependencies>
```

and you should be good to go.

Comment: Will just `cd`ing into the venv activate it?

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade/reinstall `pip`, which should fix the link, with

```py
python3 -m pip install -U --ignore-installed pip
```

This will (probably) make your global `pip` command run it on that Python 3 interpreter.